# C++11: Overload fails to resolve recursive decltype

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, decltype, trailing-return-type

In the following piece of code, I'm trying to build a lattice of types.  For instance, between `float` and `int`, promote the result to `float`:

```
float join(float f, int)   { return f; }
float join(float f, float) { return f; }
```

Then I introduce a `wrapper` type:

```
template <typename Inner>
struct wrapper
{
  using inner_t = Inner;
  inner_t value;
};
```

whose behavior with the `join` operation quite natural:

```
template <typename Inner1, typename Inner2>
auto
join(const wrapper<Inner1>& w1, const wrapper<Inner2>& w2)
  -> wrapper<decltype(join(w1.value, w2.value))>
{
  return {join(w1.value, w2.value)};
}
```

It can also be `join`ed with a "scalar" type:

```
template <typename Inner1, typename T2>
auto
join(const wrapper<Inner1>& w1, const T2& value2)
  -> wrapper<decltype(join(w1.value, value2))>
{
  return {join(w1.value, value2)};
}
```

So far, so good, it works.  But then, because in the real case I actually have many more such rules, I'd like to avoid duplicating the number of rules to express the commutativity of the `join` operation, and therefore, I express that `join(scalar, wrapper) := join(wrapper, scalar)` (In fact, I'd prefer something like `join(v1, v2) := join(v2, v1)`, but let's start with something more specific.):

```
template <typename T1, typename Inner2>
auto
join(const T1& value1, const wrapper<Inner2>& w2)
  -> decltype(join(w2, value1))
{
  return join(w2, value1);
}
```

this works properly for `join(scalar, scalar)`, `join(wrapper, scalar)` and `join(scalar, wrapper)`.  But then `join(wrapper, wrapper)` results in an infinite expansions of template functions with both G++ 4.9 and Clang++ 3.5, which I don't understand.

```
int main()
{
  int i;
  float f;
  wrapper<float> fr;
  join(f, i);
  join(fr, i);
  join(i, fr);
  join(fr, fr); // Loops.
}
```

Clang:

```
clang++-mp-3.5 -std=c++11 bar.cc
bar.cc:21:5: fatal error: recursive template instantiation exceeded maximum depth of
      256
    join(const wrapper<Inner1>& w1, const T2& value2)
    ^
bar.cc:29:5: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function
      template 'join' [with T1 = wrapper<float>, Inner2 = float]
    join(const T1& value1, const wrapper<Inner2>& w2)
    ^
```

GCC:

```
g++-mp-4.9 -std=c++11 bar.cc
bar.cc:30:34: error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use -ftemplate-depth= to increase the maximum) substituting 'template<class T1, class Inner2> decltype (join(w2, value1)) join(const T1&, const wrapper<Inner2>&) [with T1 = <missing>; Inner2 = <missing>]'
       -> decltype(join(w2, value1))
                                  ^
bar.cc:30:34:   recursively required by substitution of 'template<class T1, class Inner2> decltype (join(w2, value1)) join(const T1&, const wrapper<Inner2>&) [with T1 = wrapper<float>; Inner2 = float]'
bar.cc:30:34:   required by substitution of 'template<class T1, class Inner2> decltype (join(w2, value1)) join(const T1&, const wrapper<Inner2>&) [with T1 = wrapper<float>; Inner2 = float]'
bar.cc:43:18:   required from here
```

I do not understand why overloading does not cut the recursion.  What is going on?  There is probably a possible alternative implementation with (class) template specialization, but I'm not looking for alternative implementations: I'd like to understand what's wrong with this one.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: aren't your `join(wrapper, wrapper) = wrapper`, `join(wrapper, wrapper) = scalar` ambiguous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems with this, and one of them leads to the error.

```
template <typename Inner1, typename T2>
auto
join(const wrapper<Inner1>& w1, const T2& value2)  // (A)
  -> wrapper<decltype(join(w1.value, value2))>;
```

The name lookup of `join` here will not find the same function template via unqualified lookup, as the *trailing-return-type* is part of the declaration, and names can only be found *once they **have** been declared*. But the syntax allows ADL to find the same function template. ADL for dependent names is performed later (from the point of instantiation).

As far as I understood the problem, the issue comes from overload resolution: Before `decltype(join(w1.value, value2))` tries to resolve to an overload, all function templates with that name need to be instantiated. For each function template, one instantiation is added to the overload set (if instantiation succeeds).

Therefore, all `join`s need to be *instantiated*. Instantiation includes determining the return type. For every instantiation of this particular `join` function template (A), the same function template (A) with the same template arguments is a candidate for the overload resolution set. *That is, to determine which return type (A) has, there needs to be an overload resolution, which requires to determine the return type of (A) and so on.*

Deduction & substitution never fails in any single step of the recursion, the only reason *not* to choose this overload is partial ordering between the *different* function templates called `join`. And partial ordering is only checked *as part of* the overload resolution process -- which is too late to prevent further instantiations.

This error, as mentioned in the error message, occurs as an implementation limit. Therefore, it does not fall into the SFINAE category, see [Solving the SFINAE problem for expressions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2634.html). Therefore, even if this overload is not chosen, its mere existence makes the program ill-formed, just like

```
struct tag_for_ADL {};

template<class T>
auto foo(T p) -> decltype(foo(p));

foo(tag_for_ADL{}); // ill-formed, leads to infinite recursive instantiation
```

Comment: so my understanding is that the main problem with my code is that I don't spell out the namespace?  This can easily be addressed and seems to be working as I was expecting: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47378b37eb430b62.  Is there a trap I might have overlooked?

Comment: @akim When only relying on unqualified lookup, you won't be able to join something like `wrapper<wrapper<int>>` with anything.

Comment: you mean "qualified lookup" I guess.  Bummer :(  Thanks for your help!  Now I need to understand how to find the proper implementation :)

Comment: @dyp: but when mixing both, (and correct order), we may `join` `wrapper<wrapper<float>>` [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/addddce1cdedd862). :)

Comment: @Jarod42 That's a clever workaround, but maybe a bit too clever ;) How about [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1fdc5be47a60cb9)?

Answer (score 0):

Define `join_traits` template. Specialize for scalars and for wrappers. Use

```
join_traits<T1>::type
join_traits<T2>::type
```

and/or

```
join_traits<T1>::get_value(v1)
join_traits<T2>::get_value(v2)
```

in your single function template

```
template<class T1, class T2>
auto join (T1 v1, T2 v2) -> ...
```

Comment: I think this answer could do with a bit more explanation of how and why this could be used to solve the problem. At the moment, I think it only helps those who would have been likely to come up with it themselves.

Comment: @Agentlien: as for "how", are there really two different ways to do that? As for "why" I thought it's obvious, you define N traits and one function template instead of N^2 of whatever.

Comment: To reformulate: Your answer only declares the existence of a template type, the names of two of its potential members and a partial prototype of a function (skipping the one vital detail). I do agree that it's a good solution and that there aren't many sensible ways of implementing it. However, I still think you could afford writing at least a full implementation of the `join` function and explaining how it solves the issue. As I mentioned in my last comment: at present, I think this answer would fail to help most people who would need help answering this question.

Comment: @Agentlien Perhaps you are right, I will expand the answer when I get some quiet time.