# Non-terminating recursive function template instantiation does not produce a substitution failure

Tags: c++, overloading, sfinae, overload-resolution

Consider the follwing code (based on an [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150128171917/http://flamingdangerzone.com:80/cxx11/2013/03/11/overload-ranking.html) by [Xeo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500104/xeo)) for prioritizing function overloads:

```
template <bool condition>
using EnableIf = typename std::enable_if<condition, int>::type;


template <std::size_t n>
struct OverloadPriority
    : OverloadPriority<n - 1>
{}; 

template <>
struct OverloadPriority<0> {};



namespace impl {
    template <int x, EnableIf<x % 11 == 0>...>
    void f(OverloadPriority<5>) { std::cout << x << " is multiple of 11\n"; }
    
    template <int x, EnableIf<x % 7 == 0>...>
    void f(OverloadPriority<4>) { std::cout << x << " is multiple of 7\n"; }
    
    template <int x, EnableIf<x % 5 == 0>...>
    void f(OverloadPriority<3>) { std::cout << x << " is multiple of 5\n"; }
    
    template <int x, EnableIf<x % 3 == 0>...>
    void f(OverloadPriority<2>) { std::cout << x << " is multiple of 3\n"; }
    
    template <int x, EnableIf<x % 2 == 0>...>
    void f(OverloadPriority<1>) { std::cout << x << " is multiple of 2\n"; }
    
    template <int x>
    void f(OverloadPriority<0>) { std::cout << x << " is multiple of 1\n"; }
}

template <int x>
auto f()
    -> decltype(impl::f<x>(OverloadPriority<5>{}))
{
    return impl::f<x>(OverloadPriority<5>{});
}

int main() {
    f<10>();
    return 0;
}
```

Which works as expected.

Now, I want to bring `f`s from `impl` into file scope together with the dispatching `f`, like this:

```
template <int x, EnableIf<x % 11 == 0>...>
void f(OverloadPriority<5>) { std::cout << x << " is multiple of 11\n"; }

template <int x, EnableIf<x % 7 == 0>...>
void f(OverloadPriority<4>) { std::cout << x << " is multiple of 7\n"; }

template <int x, EnableIf<x % 5 == 0>...>
void f(OverloadPriority<3>) { std::cout << x << " is multiple of 5\n"; }

template <int x, EnableIf<x % 3 == 0>...>
void f(OverloadPriority<2>) { std::cout << x << " is multiple of 3\n"; }

template <int x, EnableIf<x % 2 == 0>...>
void f(OverloadPriority<1>) { std::cout << x << " is multiple of 2\n"; }

template <int x>
void f(OverloadPriority<0>) { std::cout << x << " is multiple of 1\n"; }

template <int x>
auto f()
    -> decltype(f<x>(OverloadPriority<5>{}))
{
    return f<x>(OverloadPriority<5>{});
}
```

Now gcc-4.8.1 tells me that the the last dispatching `f()` exceeds maximum template instantiation depth in trailing return type:

```
template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use -ftemplate-depth= to increase the maximum) substituting 'template<int x> decltype (f<x>(OverloadPriority<5ul>{})) f() [with int x = 10]'
     -> decltype(f<x>(OverloadPriority<5>{}))
```

I expect `f()` itself to be quietly SFINAEed out. Why is this an error and not just a substitution failure?

Comment: The instantiation depth is exceeded before substitution fails: overload resolution happens *after* substitution.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21813845

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24036357