# constexpr to concatenate two or more char strings

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constexpr

I'm trying to make a constexpr function that will concatenate an arbitrary number of char arrays by working from the following answer by Xeo, which concatenates two char arrays.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13294458/1128289

```
#include <array>

template<unsigned... Is> struct seq{};
template<unsigned N, unsigned... Is>
struct gen_seq : gen_seq<N-1, N-1, Is...>{};
template<unsigned... Is>
struct gen_seq<0, Is...> : seq<Is...>{};

template<unsigned N1, unsigned... I1, unsigned N2, unsigned... I2>
constexpr std::array<char const, N1+N2-1> concat(char const (&a1)[N1], char const (&a2)[N2], seq<I1...>, seq<I2...>){
  return {{ a1[I1]..., a2[I2]... }};
}

template<unsigned N1, unsigned N2>
constexpr std::array<char const, N1+N2-1> concat(char const (&a1)[N1], char const (&a2)[N2]){
  return concat(a1, a2, gen_seq<N1-1>{}, gen_seq<N2>{});
}
```

My attempt thus far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template<unsigned... Is> struct seq{};
template<unsigned N, unsigned... Is>
struct gen_seq : gen_seq<N-1, N-1, Is...>{};
template<unsigned... Is>
struct gen_seq<0, Is...> : seq<Is...>{};

template<unsigned N1, unsigned... I1, unsigned N2, unsigned... I2>
constexpr const std::array<char, N1+N2-1>
concat_impl(
    const char (&a1)[N1], const char (&a2)[N2], seq<I1...>, seq<I2...>)
{
    return {{ a1[I1]..., a2[I2]... }};
}

template<unsigned N1, unsigned N2>
constexpr const std::array<char, N1+N2-1>
concat(const char (&a1)[N1], const char (&a2)[N2])
{
    return concat_impl(a1, a2, gen_seq<N1-1>{}, gen_seq<N2>{});
}

template<unsigned N1, unsigned N2, class... Us>
constexpr auto
concat(const char(&a1)[N1], const char(&a2)[N2], const Us&... xs)
-> std::array<char, N1 + decltype(concat(a2, xs...))::size() - 1>
{
    return concat(a1, concat(a2, xs...));
}

int main()
{
    auto const s = concat("hi ", "there!");
    std::cout << s.data() << std::endl;
    // compile error:
    auto const t = concat("hi ", "there ", "how ", "are ", "you?");
    std::cout << t.data() << std::endl;
}
```

Both gcc 4.9 and clang 3.5 give errors indicating that no function matching the `concat` inside the `decltype` expression can be found.

clang:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'concat'
    auto const t = concat("hi ", "there ", "how ", "are ", "you?");
                   ^~~~~~
ctconcat.cpp:105:16: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with N1 = 4, N2 = 7, Us = <char [5], char [5], char [5]>]: no matching function for call to 'concat'
constexpr auto concat(const char(&a1)[N1], const char(&a2)[N2], const Us&... xs) -> std::array<char, N1 + decltype(concat(a2, xs...))::size() - 1>
               ^                                                                                                   ~~~~~~
ctconcat.cpp:62:43: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 5 were provided
constexpr const std::array<char, N1+N2-1> concat(const char (&a1)[N1], const char (&a2)[N2])
                                          ^
1 error generated.
```

The errors from gcc and clang both indicate that the second `concat` function template is not a candidate for the `concat` in the `decltype` expression. Only the first template is considered. Why is that and how do I fix this?

**Edit:** Relevant question on why `decltype` can't be used recursively

[trailing return type using decltype with a variadic template function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744400/trailing-return-type-using-decltype-with-a-variadic-template-function)

Comment: Am I missing something but what's wrong with `"hi " "there!"` which will also concatenate the strings?

Comment: As far as I can see, this is a basic name lookup problem: within the trailing-return-type, the function (template) has not been declared yet and hence is not found by pure unqualified lookup. ADL can find it, though.

Comment: @dyp Ah, makes sense. ADL can find it? How? Wait, no... I'm confused again... the problem occurs upon instantiation, not declaration.

Comment: @NeilKirk This is for when that's not an option. The strings will not be known until compile time (as opposed to authorship-time of the template).

Comment: ADL won't find `concat` since that function template is *not* associated with the global namespace e.g. through the types of its function parameters or its template arguments. To look up names of functions in calls that depend on template parameters, ADL will also be performed from the point of instantiation, which is after the declaration is completed and the function template (its name) can be found. For example, try to add a template parameter that is filled with a class type that is declared in the global namespace. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21815838

Comment: I find it noteworthy that usage of both `decltype` and `std::array` can be [entirely avoided](https://github.com/xamidi/pmGenerator/blob/eaf36a24548c6859ea653d1f0ebf60bbb5be82a1/helper/Version.h?ts=4#L78-L179) for [maximum compatibility](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vuUZTyJqkEafztwP).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
template<size_t S>
using size=std::integral_constant<size_t, S>;

template<class T, size_t N>
constexpr size<N> length( T const(&)[N] ) { return {}; }
template<class T, size_t N>
constexpr size<N> length( std::array<T, N> const& ) { return {}; }

template<class T>
using length_t = decltype(length(std::declval<T>()));
constexpr size_t sum_string_sizes() { return 0; }
template<class...Ts>
constexpr size_t sum_string_sizes( size_t i, Ts... ts ) {
  return (i?i-1:0) + sum_sizes(ts...);
}
```

then

```
template
template<unsigned N1, unsigned N2, class... Us>
constexpr auto
concat(const char(&a1)[N1], const char(&a2)[N2], const Us&... xs)
-> std::array<char, sum_string_sizes( N1, N2, length_t<Us>::value... )+1 >
{
  return concat(a1, concat(a2, xs...));
}
```

which gets rid of the recursion-in-`decltype`.

---

Here is a full example using the above approach:

```
template<size_t S>
using size=std::integral_constant<size_t, S>;

template<class T, size_t N>
constexpr size<N> length( T const(&)[N] ) { return {}; }
template<class T, size_t N>
constexpr size<N> length( std::array<T, N> const& ) { return {}; }

template<class T>
using length_t = decltype(length(std::declval<T>()));

constexpr size_t string_size() { return 0; }
template<class...Ts>
constexpr size_t string_size( size_t i, Ts... ts ) {
  return (i?i-1:0) + string_size(ts...);
}
template<class...Ts>
using string_length=size< string_size( length_t<Ts>{}... )>;

template<class...Ts>
using combined_string = std::array<char, string_length<Ts...>{}+1>;

template<class Lhs, class Rhs, unsigned...I1, unsigned...I2>
constexpr const combined_string<Lhs,Rhs>
concat_impl( Lhs const& lhs, Rhs const& rhs, seq<I1...>, seq<I2...>)
{
  // the '\0' adds to symmetry:
  return {{ lhs[I1]..., rhs[I2]..., '\0' }};
}

template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
constexpr const combined_string<Lhs,Rhs>
concat(Lhs const& lhs, Rhs const& rhs)
{
  return concat_impl(
    lhs, rhs,
    gen_seq<string_length<Lhs>{}>{},
    gen_seq<string_length<Rhs>{}>{}
 );
}

template<class T0, class T1, class... Ts>
constexpr const combined_string<T0, T1, Ts...>
concat(T0 const&t0, T1 const&t1, Ts const&...ts)
{
  return concat(t0, concat(t1, ts...));
}

template<class T>
constexpr const combined_string<T>
concat(T const&t) {
  return concat(t, "");
}
constexpr const combined_string<>
concat() {
  return concat("");
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/894992d09b9e99a2)

Comment: I have a follow up question on this, if you would be so kind!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39199564/c-constexpr-c-string-concatenation-parameters-used-in-a-constexpr-context

Comment: The example doesn't compile for Visual Studio 2015. ........\src\tsd.nav.sdk.mapdisplay.rmw\app\rmw_test\test2.cpp(30): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: "..."     (more following)   Ideas?

Comment: @user MSVC has poor `decltype` support.  I would try, on clsng/gcc, taking my code and moving the `length_t` `decltype` aliases and bubbling them up towards the plades they are used so `length` is used directly there in trailing return types.

Comment: `clang++` on **coliru** fails with long error list, rest of message `fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]

20 errors generated.`

Comment: Can you please add comments to code to explain what every element do.

Comment: @kyb C++1z on coliru needs a different standard library.  Or just chang it to C++14 (or probably C++11) and the live example still compiles.  I am uncertain what parts of my code confuse you.  The code was aimed at someone who would write the OP's code and understand it, or read it and ponder why it isn't working.    All I did was write a constexpr and template length calculator and modify the OP's solution to use it.

Answer (score 10):

With C++17 the solution becomes very simple ([here's the live version](https://godbolt.org/z/s8jrv3)):

```
#include <initializer_list>

// we cannot return a char array from a function, therefore we need a wrapper
template <unsigned N>
struct String {
  char c[N];
};

template<unsigned ...Len>
constexpr auto cat(const char (&...strings)[Len]) {
  constexpr unsigned N = (... + Len) - sizeof...(Len);
  String<N + 1> result = {};
  result.c[N] = '\0';

  char* dst = result.c;
  for (const char* src : {strings...}) {
    for (; *src != '\0'; src++, dst++) {
      *dst = *src;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

// can be used to build other constexpr functions
template<unsigned L>
constexpr auto makeCopyright(const char (&author)[L]) {
  return cat("\xC2\xA9 ", author);
}

constexpr char one[] = "The desert was the apotheosis of all deserts";
constexpr char two[] = "huge, standing to the sky";

constexpr auto three = cat(
  cat(one, ", ", two).c, // can concatenate recursively
  " ",
  "for what looked like eternity in all directions."); // can use in-place literals

constexpr auto phrase = cat(
  three.c, // can reuse existing cats
  "\n",
  makeCopyright("Stephen King").c);

#include <cstdio>
int main() {
  puts(phrase.c);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Why multilevel `cat` stops work if I change `String<N + 1> result = {};` to local `struct { char c[N]; } result = {};`?

Comment: Instead of a wrapper you can just use `std::array`

Comment: @JorgeBellon How?  I gave this a try and ran into the wall at `three`.  Basically with an `std::array<char, N>`, I can use `.data()` to get a `const char*`, but I need a `char[Len]`.  I can't figure out a clean way to make it work with an `std::array` *and* be able to call `cat` recursively.  I hit the same issue with your answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75619411/1861346

Comment: `std::array<char, N>::data()` should return `char*`. In any case, you can use iterators. Check my answer, which does not use any user defined types.

Answer (score 4):

Since C++20 `std::copy` family of functions is constexpr, so you can further simplify [@spiderface answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65440575/5809597):

```
template<unsigned ...Len>
constexpr auto cat(const char (&...strings)[Len]) {
  constexpr unsigned N = (... + Len) - sizeof...(Len);
  std::array<char, N + 1> result = {};
  result[N] = '\0';

  auto it = result.begin();
  (void)((it = std::copy_n(strings, Len-1, it), 0), ...);
  return result;
}
```

See https://godbolt.org/z/6xsMcqoor

Comment: Thanks for the update ! Getting really compact, nice.
Could you help me out with this line: `constexpr auto cat(const char (&...strings)[Len]) {`.
What is happening with that argument ?  It variadic, OK. And a reference to a raw array ?

Comment: The raw array is because the type of a literal string is always `const char[]`. If you let the string literals to decay to pointers, you will lose the size information, which we need here to do the copy.
See _ordinary string literal_ in: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fix compatibility issues with old 'partial' C++11 compilers is to get rid of using `decltype` entirely. I experimented with this, and [found a way](https://github.com/xamidi/pmGenerator/blob/494bd31d6c89bcd158963067064409fd4332f2e7/helper/Version.h?ts=4#L76-L177) that exploits the type system similar to how [this compile-time Turing machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/275295) works. The approach also does not use `std::array`, and allows to assign results to fully working `constexpr const char*` variables.

1. Introduce some C++14 features in C++11:

   ```
    // Parameter pack helpers (similar to C++14)
    template<std::size_t ...> struct _index_sequence { using type = _index_sequence; };
    template<std::size_t N, std::size_t ... S> struct gen_pack_sequence: gen_pack_sequence<N - 1, N - 1, S...> {};
    template<std::size_t ... S> struct gen_pack_sequence<0, S...> : _index_sequence<S...> {};
    template<std::size_t N> using _make_index_sequence = typename gen_pack_sequence<N>::type;
   ```
2. Several of the `TypeList` templates from the Turing machine, with two additional features:

   ```
    template<typename List> struct PopFront;
    template<typename OldItem, typename ... Items> struct PopFront<TypeList<OldItem, Items...>> { typedef TypeList<Items...> type; };

    template<typename ... T> struct ConcatStringList;
    template<typename S, typename ... First, typename ... Second, typename ... Tail> struct ConcatStringList<TypeList<First...>, TypeList<S, Second...>, Tail...> {
        typedef typename ReplaceItem<TypeList<First...>, GetSize<TypeList<First...>>::value - 1, S>::type first;
        typedef typename PopFront<TypeList<S, Second...>>::type second;
        typedef typename ConcatList<first, second>::type concat;
        typedef typename ConcatStringList<concat, Tail...>::type type;
    };
    template<typename T> struct ConcatStringList<T> { typedef T type; };
   ```
3. A templated struct to contain the data:

   ```
    template<char ... Chars> struct to_list { typedef typelist::TypeList<typelist::Char<Chars>...> type; };
    template<char ... Chars> struct char_sequence {
        static constexpr char value[] = { Chars... };
        typedef typename to_list<Chars...>::type list;
        template<template<char...> class Template> using param_pack = Template<Chars...>;
    };
    template<char ... Chars> constexpr char char_sequence<Chars...>::value[];
    template<char ... Chars> struct char_string: char_sequence<Chars..., '\0'> {};
   ```
4. Conversion from TypeList:

   ```
    template<typename CharList, typename = _make_index_sequence<typelist::GetSize<CharList>::value>> struct list_to_string;
    template<typename CharList, std::size_t ... Indices> struct list_to_string<CharList, _index_sequence<Indices...>> {
        static_assert(sizeof...(Indices) > 0 && typelist::GetItem<CharList, sizeof...(Indices) - 1>::type::value == 0, "missing null-termination");
        typedef char_sequence<typelist::GetItem<CharList, Indices>::type::value...> type;
    };
   ```
5. Helper to define constexpr literals:

   ```
    constexpr std::size_t _strlen(char const* s, std::size_t count = 0) {
        return (*s == '\0') ? count : _strlen(s + 1, count + 1);
    }
    template<typename S, typename T> struct _struct_to_string;
    template<typename S, std::size_t ... Indices> struct _struct_to_string<S, _index_sequence<Indices...>> { typedef char_string<S::get()[Indices] ...> type; };
    template<typename S> struct struct_to_string { typedef _make_index_sequence<_strlen(S::get())> indices; typedef typename _struct_to_string<S, indices>::type type; };
    #define CONSTEXPR_STRING(name, s) \
        struct name ## __struct { constexpr static const char* get() { return s; } }; \
        typedef struct_to_string<name ## __struct>::type name
   ```
6. Finally, the struct for string concatenation:

   ```
    template<typename ... Strings> struct concatenate {
        template<typename String> using list = typename String::list;
        typedef typename list_to_string<typename typelist::ConcatStringList<list<Strings>...>::type>::type type;
    };
   ```

Usable like so:

```
// ['year', 'month' and 'day' are not literals but somehow obtained earlier]
CONSTEXPR_STRING(dot, ".");
typedef concatenate<year, dot, month, dot, day>::type date;
constexpr const char* c_date = date::value;
```

It [compiles with GCC 4.9.4](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vuUZTyJqkEafztwP). (I can also confirm that it works with GCC 4.8.5.)