# How to declare constexpr C string?

Tags: c++, constexpr, c-strings, string-literals

I think i quite understand how to use the keyword `constexpr` for simple variable types, but i'm confused when it comes to pointers to values.

I would like to declare a constexpr C string literal, which will behave like

```
#define my_str "hello"
```

That means the compiler inserts the C string literal into every place where i enter this symbol, and i will be able to get its length at compile-time with sizeof.

Is it `constexpr char * const my_str = "hello";`

or `const char * constexpr my_str = "hello";`

or `constexpr char my_str [] = "hello";`

or something yet different?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

> Is it `constexpr char * const my_str = "hello";`

No, because a string literal is not convertible to a *pointer to `char`*. (It used to be prior to C++11, but even then the conversion was deprecated).

> or `const char * constexpr my_str = "hello";`

No. `constexpr` cannot go there.

This would be well formed:

```
constexpr const char * my_str = "hello";
```

but it does not satify this:

> So that i will be able to get its length at compile-time with sizeof, etc.

---

> or `constexpr char my_str [] = "hello";`

This is well formed, and you can indeed get the length at compile time with `sizeof`. Note that this size is the size of the array, not the length of the string i.e. the size includes the null terminator.

Comment: I understand the value of explaining the actual type, but why not proposing using simply `constexpr auto`?

Comment: is `constexpr auto my_str = "hello";` okay?

Answer (score 27):

In [C++17](https://isocpp.org/), you can use [`std::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) and [`string_view_literals`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/operator%22%22sv)

```
using namespace std::string_view_literals;
constexpr std::string_view my_str = "hello, world"sv;
```

Then,

`my_str.size()` is compile time constant.

Comment: Note that, in general, `string_view::data` does not guarantee a null-terminated string.

Comment: In general, yes. But in this particular case, the `string_view` is referring to a null-terminated string literal, so `data()` will be null-terminated.

Answer (score 0):

## C++11

Due to the null-termination of `constexpr const char*` string literals, you can simply use [std::strlen](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen), and if it ought to work compile-time, a custom function is easily definable:

```
constexpr std::size_t _strlen(char const* s, std::size_t count = 0) {
    return (*s == '\0') ? count : _strlen(s + 1, count + 1);
}
```

(C++11 constexpr functions can only contain [exactly one return statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr), so use recursion.)

If `sizeof` has to *additionally* work like on arrays (i.e. included the null-termination), you can define string literals using [variadic templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) like so:

```
constexpr std::size_t _strlen(char const* s, std::size_t count = 0) {
    return (*s == '\0') ? count : _strlen(s + 1, count + 1);
}

// Parameter pack helpers (similar to C++14)
template<std::size_t ...> struct _index_sequence { using type = _index_sequence; };
template<std::size_t N, std::size_t ... S> struct gen_pack_sequence: gen_pack_sequence<N - 1, N - 1, S...> {};
template<std::size_t ... S> struct gen_pack_sequence<0, S...> : _index_sequence<S...> {};
template<std::size_t N> using _make_index_sequence = typename gen_pack_sequence<N>::type;

template<char ... Chars> struct char_sequence {
    static constexpr char value[] = { Chars... };
    template<template<char...> class Template> using param_pack = Template<Chars...>;
};
template<char ... Chars> constexpr char char_sequence<Chars...>::value[];
template<char ... Chars> struct char_string: char_sequence<Chars..., '\0'> {};

// Compile-time string literals ; Concept: https://ideone.com/QvXuYf
template<typename S, typename T> struct _struct_to_string;
template<typename S, std::size_t ... Indices> struct _struct_to_string<S, _index_sequence<Indices...>> { typedef char_string<S::get()[Indices] ...> type; };
template<typename S> struct struct_to_string { typedef _make_index_sequence<_strlen(S::get())> indices; typedef typename _struct_to_string<S, indices>::type type; };
#define CONSTEXPR_STRING(name, s) \
    struct name ## __struct { constexpr static const char* get() { return s; } }; \
    typedef struct_to_string<name ## __struct>::type name
```

Usage with [output](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9stCzE3EryyIqwcV):

```
CONSTEXPR_STRING(var, "Hello!");

constexpr const char* _var = var::value;
constexpr std::size_t _varlen = _strlen(_var);

int main()
{
    std::cout << _var << std::endl; // "Hello!" has length 6
    std::cout << _varlen << std::endl; // 6
    std::cout << _strlen(_var) << std::endl; // 6
    std::cout << std::strlen(_var) << std::endl; // 6
    std::cout << sizeof(var::value) << std::endl; // 7: size of { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '!', '\0' }
    std::cout << sizeof(_var) << std::endl; // 8: a pointer is 64 bits = 8 bytes
}
```

This might seem overkill for one could simply use an array like

```
constexpr char _var[] = "hello";
```

but using `::value` circumvents the problems that C-style arrays [cannot be return values of functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array_rvalues) and there are [no constexpr parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) in C++. The `char_string` type can be extended to support all possible constexpr string features and is in particular flexible via using `::param_pack`, which comes in handy for example w.r.t. compile-time [string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76334795). ([Here](https://github.com/xamidi/pmGenerator/blob/dd29163745c38c3e8d6dd871be6e3929f4dcaa45/helper/Version.h?ts=4#L221) is an example of how it can be used.)

Comment: Why use recursion for this? It is painful in debug builds.

Comment: @AngelicosPhosphoros I found the reference on cppreference and linked it in my answer as well.