# Why can't a pointer to __func__ be a template argument?

Tags: c++, templates

Why I can't pass this pointer as a template argument:

```
template <const char* T>
struct MyStruct
{};

int main()
{

    static constexpr const char* func_name = nullptr; 
    MyStruct<func_name>{}; // Works
    static constexpr const char* func_name2 = __func__;
    MyStruct<func_name2>{};
    // A template argument may not reference a non-external entity
    // MyStruct: invalid expression as a template argument for 'T'
//error: the address of ‘__func__’ is not a valid template argument
}
```

I want to pass the name of the function as a template argument, and no workaround seems possible. Why?

According to the GCC documentation:

> The identifier `__func__` is implicitly declared by the translator as if, immediately following the opening brace of each function definition, the declaration
>
> ```
> static const char __func__[] = "function-name";
> ```

So it's as if it's declaring that inside the function, then I assign my constexpr `const char*` to it, and then pass it as the template argument. That should work, does it not?

I know that there are gotchas when it comes to `const char*` as a template argument. Before I was having trouble with passing a string literal (they're not allowed as template arguments). But in this case it seems I'm passing the address of a static array, which is a valid argument, no?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to declare constexpr C string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100310/how-to-declare-constexpr-c-string)

Comment: @dewaffled I know how to declare it constexpr, I did in my code, but I think the problem is that it's pointing to what __func__ declares, and it won't accept that as a template argument.

Comment: It has little to do with `__func__` because if you replace that by a string constant, it's still rejected.

Comment: Presumably it's because *a template argument may not reference a non-external entity*.

Comment: @Zebrafish The answer you've gotten seems to be pretty spot on, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3):

`__func__` is explicitly disallowed.

> **[temp.arg.nontype]**
>
> [3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.arg.nontype#3) For a non-type template-parameter of reference or pointer type, or for each non-static data member of reference or pointer type in a non-type template-parameter of class type or subobject thereof, the reference or pointer value shall not refer to or be the address of (respectively):
>
> - [...]
> - a predefined `__func__` variable ([dcl.fct.def.general]), or
> - [...]

So GCC is correct.

You should also note that the GCC documentation states it is "as if" there is such a variable. There doesn't have to be one.

The content and exact whereabouts of `__func__` is implementation defined, so just like string literals it is not constrained enough to play well with the one-definition rule when determining the linkage of templated entities.